# header renders diff on diff browser

Tags: html, xhtml, css

My web page's header looks smaller in Chrome than in FireFox. Any idea why? How can I make them look the same?

Comment: Welcome to browser quirks.  Read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/.  Then perhaps **update** your question to be more specific.

Comment: @S.Lott - header height varies in FF and Chrome

Comment: No it doesn't. At least not in FF 4.0 and Chrome 10.0.648.204

Comment: Can you make sure you're pointing to a page that exists and the issue still happens on? Screenshots pointing out the difference would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS reset and many of your problems will go away.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

By default many of the html styles and setting are different between browsers. The best thing to do is "reset" (clear) them and style them the way YOU want them to appear.

Comment: If all you're using YUI for is the reset, it's most definitely overkill (and over-loading)  There's far more streamlined resets available.